# Sorting of the port number based on the payload value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

```
from collections import defaultdict

INPUT = "/Users/amanshah/Desktop/hsn/a.tcp"

payloads = defaultdict(int)

with open(INPUT) as inf:
    for line in inf:
        values  = line.split()
        port    = int(values[1])
        payload = int(values[5])
        payloads[port] += payload

for port in sorted(payloads):
            print("{}: {}".format(port, payloads[port]))
text.close()
```

Here I am getting the output of all ports with their corresponding payload (sum) now my question is how to sort the port number based on payload as in port with max payload should come first ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort based on values not keys:

```
for k, v in sorted(payloads.iteritems(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True):
    print("{}: {}".format(k, v))
```

Since all you are doing is keeping count here, you can also use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this and then use its [`most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method:

```
from collections import Counter

payloads = Counter()

...

for k, v in payloads.most_common():
    print("{}: {}".format(k, v))
```